# Swift Key Value - advice needed

Tags: ios, swift

I have class which gets the users current location, and then GEOCODE to a proper location. I then want to send the change to the view controller. I want to be able to get the geolocation on the  observeValueForKeyPath function. Then I want to put this function in the ViewController, so when it changes I want a label to change.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, e) -> Void in
            if let error = e {
                println("Error:  (e.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                let placemark = placemarks.last as! CLPlacemark
                self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "LocationString", options: .New, context: &self.myContext)
                self.LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                self.LocationString = "\(placemark.subLocality), \(placemark.locality)"
                println("\(placemark.subLocality), \(placemark.locality)")
            }
        })



    }


    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject: AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, declare `LocationString` as dynamic in whatever class the property is in. This enables KVO for that property.

```
dynamic var LocationString: String = ""
```

Setup KVO in your view controller's `viewDidLoad()`. Remember to remove KVO somewhere in your code. Since `LocationString` is a property of another class, get a reference to that class. You can initialize the object in `viewDidLoad()` or make it a singleton and get the instance that way. I am going to go with the singleton instance, which I am going to call `Location` for this piece of code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let location = Location.sharedInstance()
    location.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "LocationString", options: .allZeros, context: nil)
}
```

Now in your view controller, `observerValueForKeyPath(...)` will be called anytime `LocationString` is changed on the `Location` singleton.

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    let location = Location.sharedInstance()
    self.label.text = location.LocationString
}
```

Comment: cannot add within ViewDidLoad as its a class.. I have done the dynamic var bit already. It is now working but I put the observeValueForKeyPath function in my view controller it complains saying An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.